# Microsoft Teams API - Removing a member from channel returns [400] - BadRequest: Invalid id

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Am trying to remove a user from a channel using the remove user from channel using [this API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example)

Im getting 400 invalid id response on my user ID.

I've checked and my team, channel and user ID are all correct, and I'm trying to delete the user from a private channel as stated in the API and yet get the response.

This is the url passed: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team_aad_id}/channels/{channel_id}/members/{team_member_id}`

The headers are the following:

```
{
   'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json'
}
```

And I have all the permissions stated in the API.
`Chat.ReadWrite.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`

Any clue what should be done?

Comment: Please try to edit your question and add more info like the code of your API call. Response 400 means "bad request". You're either missing some non-optional fields in your request or headers. Also, make sure you are sending the auth token of the user that has permissions to delete a user.

Comment: Could you please check you have [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) as mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: I added all the info I can give as well as which permissions I have.

Comment: What kind of id are you using for 'team_member_id"? Is it the object id or the upn?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - it is the same user ID I use to add a user to a channel. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-add?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http. Adding works, removing does not.

Comment: Are you the owner of the team? A owner have access to remove member from the team

Comment: I am using a Bot (application I believe) to use this command - it has been granted permissions by the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you really using the team_member_id or are you using the user_azure_id?

If you get members from channel, Response is this:

```
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "id": "MHJKIOc2NjVjMGM5ZTc1NDg2YWFiOTgyNGVkNzasrtefiNmJAdGhyZWFkLnRhY3YyIyNlYzM5OGYzYy0zNDI4LTQwOGYtOGY3OC0wMTViZWZkYWQ5OA=",
        "roles": [],
        "displayName": "John Smith",
        "userId": "popopop-3428-408f-8f78-015befdad980",
        "email": "John.Smith@te.onmicrosoft.com"
```

Where userID is Azure User ID.

To remove a member from a channel you have to provide the Channel Member Id, which is the long  **id** above